# Using transactions in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, transactions

I have two different calls to controller in Web API. Let's say that the route for a first one is http://localhost/1 and for second http://localhost/2

My goal is to do something like transactions. In a first call I want to send data to server. So this is where my first question comes: How can I save data for a short time on server, and not saving it into database? What's the best practice for this?

In second call I'm sending verification code. If code is ok, than I will do something with data that client send in previous call.

This sounds like a transaction to me. Like commit if code is ok or rollback transaction if code verification faild, but I'm not sure is it possible to use transactions in this kind of scenarios, when you have two different POST methods.

Can someone help me with thinking about this little bit more?

Comment: It seems you have to combine the verification code with the data. Normally webapi is a stateless implementation, so there is no sharing between calls.

Comment: @peer Is it good idea to keep some kind of transaction reference inside the memory, return it to client and then in second call ask client to provide transaction reference and verification code? That's something that slip on my mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Dont save anything temporarily in server. That's a bad practice.***

WebApi is stateless. So, its better to save every details in server.

1. In the first POST call, return a unique transaction reference number (Use SQL server to save this information)

   E.g. POST to **http://localhost/requestVerificationNumber/** which returns a *GUID*
2. In the second POST call, cross check the verification code by matching it with the unique transaction number stored before. It is the responsibility of the second POST call to send that reference number.

   E.g. POST to **http://localhost/verifyCode/** along with the *GUID* sent before.
   The advantage of this method is that all the transactions are stored in Sql Server and later be manipulated.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotber Thanks for answering, it gave me better idea how to implement this. :)